# Infowindow googlemaps click event gives error

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I bumped into a problem as I am adding infowindows to my markers. Although they all appear nicely and if i click on them, the windows appear, i seem to encounter a bug, and I cant figure out what it wants.

The problem lies when I click on a marker and the window appears with all the information. I get an: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'N'" error, in the main.js, something that is generated by Sencha Architect itself.

It displays however the information, and i can still open multiple screens, but the close screens dont work, which off course i want, cause i dont see reason why 150 different markers should all show content screens if i cant close them.

My code for the create marker function is as followed (note that his is run in a loop to create 150 markers)

```
var infoWindow;

// Creating a marker
var title = data.stembureau_2;
var yay = map.getMap();
var icon = 'markers/SGA.png';
var gpa = data.gpa;

if (gpa == 'Ja'){
     icon = 'markers/GPA.png';
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
     map:      yay,
     title:    title,
     icon: icon
});

// Creating an InfoWindow object
var content = data.stembureau_1;
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
});

// Loading the Infowindow on a click event
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infoWindow.open(map, this);                  
});

// Closing the Infowindow on a click event
closeInfoWindow = function() {
     infoWindow.close();
};
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', closeInfoWindow);

return marker;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed it already, quite simple. I refered earlier to yay as the map-object, which down i didnt. small error on my part i constantly overread! anyway, thank you.